# Weird loop cut and slide glitch, just some random inward mesh deformation

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image][image]

I've only had the program for a few days and the loop cut and slide deformation glitch really ruins it for me. note that i don't always have this problem but its a reocurring problem for me. Every time I try loop cut and slide this happens.
whenever i use the tool loop cut slide, blender automatically puts a huge dent in the cube.

[image]

Comment: hello, it's hard to see what you're trying to do, what happens, what is the problem, perhaps share your file or more screenshots

Comment: i dont know what else to share, whenever i try to add an edge loop through loop cut and slide it creates that weirdly shaped dent on its own, and i just want to add a single edge loop.

Comment: ok, i added another screenshot where i highlighted what i tried to do

Comment: although i said every time what i meant was i had this problem consequentially in a row for a couple models, i made the same base mesh with mirror modifyer again and now everything is fine. i don't know what happened, but all i know is this is probably a bug since there is no reason anyone would want this as a feature.

Comment: ps. i am very sorry for making this post for what is probably no reason, but i'd rather keep it here since this is very strange.

Comment: your problem is not clear at all, maybe share the cube with the problem

Comment: ok, ive put the file on the page, and note that this happens whenever one uses loop cut and slide on this cube. try it and see what happens. if nothing happens on your hand, which i wouldn't expect, then i guess i've got no explanation.

Comment: btw i have not figured it out yet but i re-did all the work, and it no longer happens when i use loop cut and slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the *X-Mirror* option in the *Tools* panel > *Options*.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer moon boots! really appreciate the help!

Comment: weird thing is, this (bug) does not happen in Blender 2.8. 2.79b creates a garbage cube, 2.8 doesn't do that with the provided file.